# on click button within v-for change this attribute vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create an 'add friend' button like facebook. When click this 'add friend' button it changes to 'friend request sent' button. I have tried following approach which doesn't work:

html:

```
<div v-for="(friend, index) in friends">
    <div v-if="friend.sentRequest">
        <button class='disabled'>Friend request sent</button>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <button @click="addFriend(friend)">Add friend</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
           return {
                friends: [],
           } 
        },

        methods: {
            addFriend(friend) {
                friend.sentRequest = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I need help to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Test this: `this.$set(friend, 'sentRequest', true)` on `addFriend(friend)` method.

Comment: you can use like **this.friend.sentRequest = true;**

Comment: yes worked like charm.. !! but i applied my approach in another place almost similar to this scenario which is working. why my approach fails here? @Damon.s

Comment: your approach is not working @Naveen

Comment: Does friend object have a  `sentRequest` property beforehand ?

Comment: It depends on how you pushing items to `friends`. @WahidSherief

Comment: no. I am creating it at runtime. @VamsiKrishna. But i remember u gave me a solution before similar as my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to define property for existing object you should to use `this.$set(target, key, value)`.

In this case use:

```
methods: {
    addFriend(friend) {
        this.$set(friend, 'sentRequest', true);
    }
}
```